# Change response code in AbstractHttpMessageConverter

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Is it possible to change the response status code in a AbstractHttpMessageConverter writeInternal() method?

In my AbstractHttpMessageConverter (extending MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) I want to change error responses to 200 and add the actual status code (e.g. 400) to a status field in the json.

**EDIT1**

I'm returning code like:

```
JSONObject json= new JSONObject();
json.put("name", "My Name");
return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(json, HttpStatus.OK);
```

or in case of an error:

```
JSONObject json= new JSONObject();
json.put("error", "My Error");
return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(json, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

Somewhere I want to intercept the response body and:
a) wrap the original response body (enity) with status code
b) change response status code to 200

So for both variants this would mean:

```
{ "status": 200, "response": { "name": "My Name" } }

{ "status": 400, "response": { "error": "My Error" } }
```

and in both case a http status 200 will be returned.

I was thinking of doing this by extending the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and overiding the writeInternal method, but unfortunately there I cannot change the status code.

Note I don NOT want to this in my controller classes. They should just return the base json structure.

Comment: In general I would consider it bad practice to put the http-code in the response body as this introduces redundancy. It may be okay in special situations though.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.  The HttpMessageConverter can set certain headers and write the body of a message, but it cannot set the status code.  Perhaps you can change the status code to 200 and set a property to 400 before sending the object to the HttpMessageConverter.

I like to use the ResponseEntity object, which allows you to set a status code along with an object, but without seeing your code, I don't know if it will work for you.